# Способы идентификации клиента для службы WCF ASP.NET приложения

Tags: asp.net, клиент-сервер, wcf

Пользователь работает в приложении ASP.NET в браузере, результаты работы на сервере сохраняет служба WCF, реализованная в этом же приложении. У пользователя на компьютере в этот момент работает клиентская программа, которая у этой WCF-службы может запрашивать полученные результаты работы пользователя, для сохранения их на компьютере пользователя.

*Есть одна нерешенная проблема, нету идентификации пользователей*: если в то время как пользователь `А` работает у себя на броузере, пользователь `B` запустит клиентскую программу, он сможет скачать данные пользователя `B`. В данный момент у меня так и работает.

Нужно как-то идентифицировать клиентские программы, в том числе когда пользователь на броузере работает как анонимный (не авторизовался).  Есть идея, использовать id текущей сессии `HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID`. Но как это значение передавать клиентской программе?

Для пользователя все должно происходить в фоновом режиме, допускаются только запросы на подтверждение операции (напр. от броузера).

У кого какие мысли?

Comment: Есть ли у браузера возможность записывать в файл на компьютере пользователя?

Comment: 1. Вот [здесь](http://forum.codenet.ru/threads/5164-Запись-чтение-из-файла(JavaScript)) обсуждается *Запись/чтение из файла(JavaScript)*. Там есть ссылка на [пример](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czxefwt8(vs.71).aspx).  
Браузер в начале каждой сессии пишет в файл `SessionId`, клиетская программа считывает.  

2. В начале сессии запускать копию клиентской программы (расположение хранить в куках) с параметром `SessionId`. Запускать можно с `JS` или `COM` (только IE).

Comment: может должно быть `он сможет скачать данные пользователя A`?